# how can i stop the aggressive compiler optimization in openCL?

Tags: optimization, opencl, global, local

I'm trying to copy a global memory array (opencl inputs) into a local memory array to reduce the memory access time of the array in the opencl kernel, since I want to read from the array frequently. I do the copy this way (ex.):

```
 __Kernel (__global float* inputs...) 
__local float in [64];

in[global_id] = inputs[global_id]
```

The problem is when I compile the kernel to run it on the board, the compiler does optimizations and it seems to remove the local memory because the compiler crashes when I write to the local memory (in) after that.

The compiler message is:

> Compiler Warning: Aggressive compiler optimization: removing
>   unnecessary storage to local memory

Even when I use the argument -cl-opt-disable in the aoc command, it still the same, as the argument do nothing.

So is there any way to stop the compiler optimization to solve this problem?

Comment: What hardware do you have? With AMD you can use `-O0` to disable optimizations.

Comment: I'm compiling it for de1soc Board (FPGA), but the cpu where the compiler runs is intel core i7.. 
now I found something new, which is when i remove another array which results from the "in" array , it stops the optimization.
like when "array3" is removed: 
array3 [global_id] = in[global_id] * 5 .
then "in"  will not be optimized anymore